# Flot x axis showing wrong time, 3 hours behind it seems

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, flot

The x axis on my flot chart is wrong and I can't for the life of me figure it out, I am multiplying php strtotime*1000

```
<?php
function timegen($time) {
$gen = strtotime("$time") * 1000;
return $gen;
}


echo("[".timegen("2014-04-16 09:30AM UTC").",".rand(5,50)."],<br>");
echo("[".timegen("2014-04-16 10:00AM UTC").",".rand(5,50)."],<br>");
echo("[".timegen("2014-04-16 11:00AM UTC").",".rand(5,50)."],<br>");
echo("[".timegen("2014-04-16 12:00PM UTC").",".rand(5,50)."],<br>");
echo("[".timegen("2014-04-16 01:00PM UTC").",".rand(5,50)."],<br>");
echo("[".timegen("2014-04-16 02:00PM UTC").",".rand(5,50)."],<br>");
echo("[".timegen("2014-04-16 03:00PM UTC").",".rand(5,50)."],<br>");
echo("[".timegen("2014-04-16 04:00PM UTC").",".rand(5,50)."],<br>");
?>
```

Which returns something like:

```
        [1397640600000,50],
        [1397642400000,5],
        [1397646000000,36],
        [1397649600000,39],
        [1397653200000,35],
        [1397656800000,39],
        [1397660400000,25],
        [1397664000000,50]
```

9:30-4:00

However the chart displays 06:00 7:00 8:00 9:00 10:00 11:00 12:00

My xaxis settings are:

```
        tickColor: 'transparent',
        mode: "time", 
        tickDecimals: 2,
        timeFormat: "%H",
        timezone: "America/New York"
```

I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me sort this out, I don't usually ask for help but I really can't seem to figure it out, new to flot

Comment: I am having the same problem, but everything is right, including the javascript time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I think it was an error in my converting times, I took UTC out of the strtotime and it fixed time on chart. I only included the UTC bit in the PHP because flot's manual had it.

Comment: If your plot is not viewed in different timezones and must show local time in all zones, it is simplest to just use UTC on the server and in flot and ignore all timezones. That is why the manual has it so.